# move and backup multiple directories with wildcards in bash

Tags: bash, directory, wildcard, move

The goal is to move multiple directories including its content to another directory while making in parallel a backup.

```
Input="/home/input/folder*/"
Output="/home/output/"
Backup="/home/backup/"

for folder in "$Input" ; do
    cp -rp "$folder" "$Backup" || { echo 'error backup'; exit; }
    cp -rp "$folder" "$Output" || { echo 'error move'; exit; }
    rm -rf "$folder"
done
```

I get following error message:`cp: cannot stat ‘/home/input/folder*/’: file or folder not found`

Two questions:

- Why does the wildcard not work?
- Is there a more elegant way to do this task?

Comment: Quotes prevent `bash` from expanding `*`.

Comment: That was it. Thank you

Comment: You can probably achieve this with a single find command also.

Comment: Would it be more elegant? If yes, then I would like to adopt such a solution

Comment: This might help: [How to copy a single file to multiple directories in Linux or Unix](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-copy-a-file-to-multiple-directories-using-cp-command/)

Comment: fwiw ... subject and description mentions **move** but the code says **copy**; unless the source and target are on different disks I'd think `mv` would be faster for the 'input > output' **move**; also, I'd be hesitant about running any `rm` commands until I knew my other operations were successful (ie, perhaps hold off on the `rm` commands until you've verified you have 100% copies in the target directories?) ...

Comment: @CyrusGreat link, I will go through it and finaly answer my own question.

Comment: @Merkp-fuso: you are absolutly right, as I am not hundert percent sure, I do usually a backup first. I am hesitant to use `mv` because it has a slightly different syntax, and speed is no problem.

Comment: If you have spaces in your file/foldernames, this will not work and in worst case you will lose data!!!

Comment: You are right,. Fortunalty this is not the case here. But it would be nice to get a foolproof script fot this kind of task

Comment: @Merk-fuso and Marco: btw for safety there was the exit clause in the copy statement to avoid just the error you proposed.

Comment: `Would it be more elegant?` "Elegant" is subjective. For me your code looks very elegenant, I would anyway use `if` instead of `||` and would also check `rm` success. Except for the problem that `"$Input"` should be changed to `"/home/input/"folder*/` and you want to add `shopt -s nullglob`, there is nothing to see here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling all your comments into an answer:

```
Input="/home/input/"folder*/
Output="/home/output/"
Backup="/home/backup/"

shopt -s nullglob

for folder in $Input ; do
    cp -rp "$folder" "$Backup" || { echo 'error backup'; exit; }
    cp -rp "$folder" "$Output" || { echo 'error move'; exit; }
    rm -rf "$folder"           || { echo 'error remove'; exit; }
done
```